# Who is this Saint?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, saint, identify-this

My sister bought me this bracelet from a monastery in Serbia. I've been searching for quite some time to find which Saint is depicted to no avail. It looks like St. John Chrysostom but I'm not sure.

[image: Saint Who?]

Comment: Is he holding two crosses or does he have two crosses on his vestments/robes?

Comment: It looks like they are on his robes to be honest and he holds a book(?)

Comment: I agree it looks like Chrysostom, but can't be certain. Can you read and post what is written to his left and right?

Comment: @Peter The crosses are part of the vestments. I think that is a _epitrachelion_.

Comment: Unfortunately not. They are written in Cyrillic and I'm not familiar with the alphabet.

Comment: I've just found it. :) https://i.pinimg.com/736x/55/82/ea/5582ea2ba3a981b285864509f4a4dda5.jpg

Comment: @ΚελεσίδηςΑντώνιος It is definitely John Chrysostom. Feel free to post more detailed pictures here, as, I believe, there are many Slavonic language  speakers here (as me for example).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is almost certainly John Chrysostom. Compare your image with the middle figure of this icon of the Three Hierarchs

[image]

The middle figure is labeled Chrysostom. To the left of him is Basil the Great. To the right is Gregory the Theologian.

Comment: Thank you. I've also found the exact same image. It is him.
https://i.pinimg.com/736x/55/82/ea/5582ea2ba3a981b285864509f4a4dda5.jpg

Comment: I was going to post what I learned by way of google reverse image search,  but  it's not enough to make a standalone answer:  Sv. Jovan Zlatousti = St. John Chrysostom is an interesting tidbit.